# After install live search in magento cloud i am getting Cannot instantiate interface Magento\ServicesId\Model\ServicesConfigInterface

Tags: magento2.4.5, liveseach

After install Live search in cloud magento its giving below errors.

```
Cannot instantiate interface Magento\ServicesId\Model\ServicesConfigInterface#0 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#1 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#2 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
```